# Giving Single tag to whole document using SVM

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, svm, text-classification

I would like to know, how to train SVM giving a whole document as input and  a single label for that input document. 
I have tagged only word by word  till now.
for example, input document may contain 6 to 10 sentences, and the whole document is to be labelled with a single class for training.

Answer (score 1):

A basic method would be as follows:

1. Create a list of your training documents and labels/classes.
2. Tokenize your training documents.
3. Remove stop words from your documents.
4. Create TF-IDF values for your documents.
5. Restrict your TF-IDF values to the N most common ones, e.g. with N=1000.
6. Train an SVM on the limited TF-IDF data and your labels.

Then you have a classifier that can map documents in TF-IDF form to class labels. Therefor you can then classify your test documents after converting them into a similar TF-IDF form.

Here is an example in Python with scikit for an SVM that classifies documents as being either about foxes or cities:

```py
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# Training examples (already tokenized, 6x fox and 6x city)
docs_train = [
    "The fox jumped over the fence .",
    "The fox sleeps under the tree .",
    "A fox walks through the high grass .",
    "Didn 't see a single fox today .",
    "I saw a fox yesterday near the lake .",
    "You might encounter foxes at the lake .",

    "New York City is full of skyscrapers .",
    "Los Angeles is a city on the west coast .",
    "I 've been to Los Angeles before .",
    "Let 's travel to Mexico City .",
    "There are no skyscrapers in Washington .",
    "Washington is a beautiful city ."
]

# Test examples (already tokenized, 2x fox and 2x city)
docs_test = [
    "There 's a fox in the garden .",
    "Did you see the fox next to the tree ?",
    "What 's the shortest way to Los Alamos ?",
    "Traffic in New York is a pain"
]

# Labels of training examples (6x fox and 6x city)
y_train = ["fox", "fox", "fox", "fox", "fox", "fox",
           "city", "city", "city", "city", "city", "city"]

# Convert training and test examples to TFIDF
# The vectorizer also removes stopwords and converts the texts to lowercase.
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=1.0, max_features=10000,
                             min_df=0, stop_words='english')

vectorizer.fit(docs_train + docs_test)

X_train = vectorizer.transform(docs_train)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(docs_test)

# Train an SVM on TFIDF data of the training documents
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Test the SVM on TFIDF data of the test documents
print clf.predict(X_test)
```

Output is as expected (2x fox and 2x city):

```
['fox' 'fox' 'city' 'city']
```